# UWP: How do I set the default tab size for a RichTextBlock?

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextblock

I have a RichTextBlock in UWP.

I need to configure how much space a tab is going to take: this is basically the same concept of the iOS primitive "defaultTabInterval": https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1529861-defaulttabinterval?language=objc

How do I achieve this goal in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, there is no API that can set the width of Tab (`\t`) independently.

As a workaround, you can try replacing all `\t` with more controllable spaces before assigning `Text` to `RichTextBlock`.

Best regards.